# There exists an deleted neighborhood around $0$ so thag a non-zero analytic function is no-where $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, power-series, roots

This is obvious if we use Identity theorem. But I can't use that since it is real analysis exercise. All I can use there exists series expansion for the function around $0$.

Since non-zero analytic function not all coefficient is $0$. So we need to find $r$ so that $0<|z| \leq r$ such that $\sum a_n z^n$ is never zero. We need to prove only using the techniques of sequence and series. How to proceed? Any help please?

Comment: identity theorem holds for real analytic functions too, but if you want another alternative assume there is $r_n \to 0, f(r_n)=0$ and wlog assume $r_n >0$ decreasing, so by Rolle you find $s_n \to 0, f'(s_n)=0$ with $s_n$ positive decreasing and use induction to find such for all derivatives; this implies $f^{(n)}(0)=0, n \ge 1$ so $f$ constant

Comment: But there is no such assumption that $f(0) =0$. And it is exercise given in sequence and series chapter so can't use continuity and differentiability.

Comment: The intuition should be that, as $z\rightarrow0$, the term $a_{n_0}z^{n_0}$ with the smallest $n_0$ s.t. $a_{n_0}\neq0$ should asymptotically dominate the series (compare the graphs to get a feel for this). Indeed, you can show that $|\sum a_nz^n|>|a_{n_0}z^{n_0}|/2$ for $z$ sufficiently small by computing the limit of the quotient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that the Taylor series of $f$ centered at $0$ is not the null series; otherwise, the statement is trivially false.

If $f(0)\ne0$, it follows from the continuity of $f$ that there is a neighborhood of $0$ at which there are no zeros of $f$. If you want to avoid assuming that $f$ is continuous, you can do it as follows: near $0$, you have\begin{align}f(x)-f(0)&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\right)-a_0\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n\\&=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}x^n.\end{align}Now, let $\rho$ be the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ and take $r\in(0,\rho)$. If $|x|<r$, it follows from what was done above that$$\bigl|f(x)-f(0)\bigr|<|x|\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_{n+1}|r^n,$$and so, if$$|x|<\frac{|f(0)|}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_{n+1}|r^n},$$then $\bigl|f(x)-f(0)\bigr|<\bigl|f(0)\bigr|$, and therefore $f(x)\in\bigl(0,2f(0)\bigr)$; in particular, $f(x)\ne0$.

And if $f(0)=0$, then let $k$ be the smallest natural number such that $a_k\ne0$. Then$$f(x)=a_kx^k\left(1+\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}x+\frac{a_{k+2}}{a_k}x^2+\cdots\right).$$If$$g(x)=1+\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}x+\frac{a_{k+2}}{a_k}x^2+\cdots,$$then $g(0)=1\ne0$ and therefore $g$ has no zeros near $0$ (as above) And, of course, $a_kx^k=0\iff x=0$. So, near $0$, the only zero of $f$ is $f$ itself.

Comment: Is it possible to prove without using continuity?

Comment: Yes, but since being analytic is *much* stronger than being continuous, why do you want to do that?

Comment: It is a exercise in sequence and series. That is why.

Comment: It's done.${}{}$

Comment: Thank you so much